# Left column doesn't display

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to use this [template](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-fixed-layout-21-fixed-fixed/) in my MVC project.

But the left column is not showing in index.aspx.
Thanks for helping me to find the error.

Site.css

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    b{font-size: 110%;}
    em{color: red;}

    #maincontainer{
    width: 840px; /*Width of main container*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*Center container on page*/
    }

    #topsection{
    background: #EAEAEA;
    height: 90px; /*Height of top section*/
    }

    #topsection h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    }

    #contentwrapper{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    }

    #contentcolumn{
    margin-left: 200px; /*Set left margin to LeftColumnWidth*/
    }

    #leftcolumn{
    float: left;
    width: 200px; /*Width of left column*/
    background: #C8FC98;
    }

     #footer{
     clear: left;
     width: 100%;
     background: black;
     color: #FFF;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 4px 0;
     }

     #footer a{
     color: #FFFF80;
     }
```

Site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="topsection" runat="server">
 <link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>
     </head>
   <body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="pageHeadPlaceHolder" runat="server">
        <div id="pageHead">
        <p>Head</p>
        </div>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <div id="mainContainer">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="leftColPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                <div id="leftcolumn">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Contact Us</li>
                        <li>About Us</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="innertube"><b>Left Column: <em>200px</em></b></div>
                </div>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            <div id="contentwrapper">
                <div id="contentcolumn">
                    <p>
                        test</p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="pageFooterPlaceHolder" runat="server">
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Index.aspx

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
          Home Page
   </asp:Content>

   <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
   <p>
            To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
   </p>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="leftColPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:Content>
```

**UPDATED Image**

[image: image updated]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the HTML output? If the left column code is not there then its not a CSS issue.  It looks like you are overwriting your left column code in the master with the blank content tag.  Try removing the following from your index.aspx.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="leftColPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:Content>
```

You only need to declare it in the index.aspx if you plan on replacing what is in the master.

Answer (score 0):

Love,

I can't see the css file included anywhere in your Site.Master. Try adding a reference to that, something along the lines of (or whatever the path to your particular css may be):

```
<link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: i think this layout 'may' require some content in order to fill the content area (i.e. make the content stretch). and btw, don't be mean, no credit for discovering the missing css ref !!?? :-)

Comment: But I have <p> test</p> in master page.

Comment: have you got it in the normal `head` area??

Comment: <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="pageHeadPlaceHolder" runat="server">
            <div id="pageHead">
            <p>Head</p>
            </div>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> Then it displays "Head".

Comment: no, i meant do you have the css link in the head area of the site.master! :)